# How can i get a file from storage without symlink?

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

I have a problem with storage.
How can I get a file from storage without symlink ?

When I try to get a video from file storage, to HTML video tag, I got a "forbidden" or "Not allowed to load local resource".

**Controller :**

```
$url = Storage::url($file);  
return view('video')->with('url',$url);
```

**HTML tag :**

```
<video width="600" height="400" controls>
         <source src="{{url($url)}}" type="video/mp4">
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
         Votre navigateur ne supporte pas le lecteur vidéo.
</video>
```

Comment: I have the same problem.

Has anyone managed to display pictures from storage - on servers where you can't use terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the storage is that it may reside in a place not accessible by your webserver, or at least nooit publicly accessible. It could be a folder, it could be an S3 storage, could be something else.

What you need to do is define a route to specifically download the video file. You can generate a temporary signed URL to that route in your controller code: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#signed-urls

Sent that signed URL to the view. Now the browser will load the video from the signed URL. You need to create the route and controller function to load the file from storage and sent it to the browser: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#downloading-files

Comment: Thank you for this, I have another question. 
How I can protect the "public/storage" route with some middleware ? Its possible ?

Comment: If the `public/storage` folder exists, the webserver wil handle requests to files to that folder on its own. It will simply sent the file to the user, without starting up your laravel application. You can define your own route to download files, all inside your laravel app, to and you can add whatever middleware you want on that route.